# JxBrowser 6.14.2 System Requirements are unclear. Browser creation fails on several Linux distros

Tags: java, linux, 64-bit, jxbrowser

I'm using JxBrowser version 6.14.2 in an application that needs to work on as many OS's as possible, The [System Requirements](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013733-system-requirements) page states that JxBrowser runs on:

> Windows, and macOS platforms (Intel and AMD), both 32- and 64-bit, and Linux 64-bit

Sidenote: 
There is a dependency for jxbrowser-linux32 alongside these at http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/ which doesn't seem to work in my 32 bit linux VMs.  Is there something I am missing to get JxBrowser working on 32bit linux systems?

I have also tested this on 64 bit VMs with Ubuntu 17.04, Centos 6.8 and Fedora 25, all Java 1.8 and I continue to get the following error:

> IPC process exited. exit code 127

People are saying I am missing a libcrypto.so.1.0.0 file but that file exists in my jxbrowser chromium dir.

Why won't JxBrowser work properly on my linux VMs? Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take into account that the [System Requirements](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013733-system-requirements) in the article that you have mentioned are specified for the latest version of JxBrowser, which is 6.17 at the moment, and JxBrowser 6.14.2 is out of date.

Here are the platforms supported by JxBrowser 6.17:

Windows (32-bit & 64-bit)

- Windows 7
- Windows 8
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 10
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows Server 2016

Linux (64-bit)

- Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop
- Ubuntu 14.04+
- Debian 8+
- Fedora 24+
- openSUSE 13.3+
- RedHat Enterprise Linux 7

macOS (64-bit)

- macOS 10.9.x - 10.13.x (Core i5, Core i7)

You can also look through the [JxBrowser release notes](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/forums/9000110576) to understand when the support of the platforms was added or removed.

For instance, Ubuntu 17.04 support was added in JxBrowser 6.16.

In addition, the Linux 32-bit support was dropped after migrating to Chromium 60 in JxBrowser 6.15, because Chromium itself does not support those platforms anymore.